# Run a corresponding unit test each time a file is saved

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

I have just switched over to using PyCharm as my primary Python editor, and am curious to know how I can configure it so that every time I save a file, that the unit-test corresponding to the modified file will be run? (after poking around the documentation, I have not found a clear explanation of how to do this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [File Watchers](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7177?pr=idea) plugin to execute task on files modification.

example config:
[image: Config]

Comment: But where is its output produced? I see the task run but no update about whether test passed or failed.

Answer (score 7):

When you run a unittest you get a new unittest window. In this window there's a button where you can toggle auto-testing on and off, see below. You can set the auto-test delay as well (look for the gear-icon in the same window.

[image: auto.test]

Comment: Would that method automatically run the unit test every time that the file is saved?

Comment: @AlexanderMarquardt No sadly not. But if you put the delay to say 3 secs it works well enough in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way that I decided to accomplish my objective.

I use file watchers (`PyCharm->Preferences->File Watchers`) to monitor the python source files for modifications. Source files are located in a directory called `src`. For my purposes, each unit test is located in a directory that is parallel to the `src` directory called `test_src`, in which each file `src/[file_name].py` will have an associated test file called `test_src/test_[file_name].py`. Unit tests will by run by `py.test`.

To accomplish this, I use the following setup in the File Watchers dialog:

```
File type: "Python Files"
Scope: "Only watch files in src directory"
Program: /usr/local/bin/py.test
Arguments: $ProjectFileDir$/test_src/test_$FileName$
Working directory: $ProjectFileDir$
```

I also unchecked "Immediate file synchronization" as I only want to run the unit tests when the file is saved.

Note that the "Scope" is used for specifying which files will be monitored.