# Disable automatically starting unit tests in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

With the latest version of PyCharm, every time I make a change, PyCharm automatically runs my unit tests for me. Much of the time, this is very convenient. Sometimes, however, I need to turn this feature off, so that my tests only run when I explicitly invoke them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was similar questions asked before: [PyCharm - run a corresponding unit test each time a file is saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981034/pycharm-run-a-corresponding-unit-test-each-time-a-file-is-saved)

Simply, turn off feature below green arrow on the left side.

From https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/test-runner-tab.html

"AutoTest   Toggle auto-test    If this button is pressed, the autotest-like runner is turned on. It means that the test in the current run configuration tab will automatically rerun on changing its source code. Otherwise, to rerun such test, you have to click the rerun button"